# appending values to lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, compare, append, dataframe

I have the following code.

```
rushingyards = 0
passingyards = 0
templist = []
combineddf = play.groupby(['GameCode','PlayType']).sum()
combineddf.to_csv('data/combined.csv', sep=',')
combineddff =pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data/combined.csv')
temp = {}
for row in combineddff.itertuples():
    if row[1] in ('RUSH', 'PASS'):
        temp['GameCode'] =  row[0]
        if row[1] == 'RUSH':
            temp['Rushingyards'] = row[10]
        else:
             temp['PassingYards'] = row[10]

    else:
        continue
    templist.append(temp)
```

The head of my combined csv is below.

```
                 PlayType  PlayNumber  PeriodNumber  Clock  OffenseTeamCode  \
GameCode                                                                      
2047220131026     ATTEMPT         779            19   2220             1896   
2047220131026  FIELD_GOAL         351             9   1057              946   
2047220131026     KICKOFF        1244            32   4388             3316   
2047220131026        PASS        8200           204   6549            14730   
2047220131026     PENALTY        1148            29   1481             2372   

               DefenseTeamCode  OffensePoints  DefensePoints  Down  Distance  \
GameCode                                                                       
2047220131026             1896            142            123   NaN       NaN   
2047220131026              476             52             51    12        17   
2047220131026             2846            231            195   NaN       NaN   
2047220131026            23190           1131           1405   147       720   
2047220131026             2842            188            198    19        84   

               Spot  DriveNumber  DrivePlay  
GameCode                                     
2047220131026    24          NaN        NaN  
2047220131026    19           49          3  
2047220131026   850          NaN        NaN  
2047220131026  3719         1161         80  
2047220131026   514          164          1
```

I have to check if the playtype is Rush or pass and accordingly create a list like following.

```
  Gamecode      rushing_yards   passingyards
  299004720130829     893          401 
  299004720130824     450          657 
  299004720130821     430          357
```

I am not able to append the values correctly. Evey time it runs, it gives all similar values of gamecode, rushing_yards and passingyards. Kindly help.

Comment: You can improve this question by reducing the code to a minimal example of the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are appending the reference to the object `temp`. You are basically just storing references to the same object which is causing the values to be the same for all of them. Put your temp dict inside the for loop and you should see resolution of this issue as it instantiates a new dict object upon each iteration in the loop.